# Jetty CXF with two hosts and same ports

Tags: jetty, cxf, apache-camel, cxfrs

The server starts normally, but ignore the second host. 
10.23.18.240 works, 10.23.18.241 don't.

**xmlns:httpj="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http-jetty/configuration"**

```
<httpj:engine-factory bus="cxf">
    <httpj:engine port="443" host="10.23.18.240">
    ...
    </httpj:engine>
    <httpj:engine port="443" host="10.23.18.241">
    ...
    </httpj:engine>
</httpj:engine-factory>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to jetty listen to all the network interfaces of the box, you should use host "0.0.0.0".

Comment: thanks @Wilelem. It doesn't fit. I want different configurations for each interface.

Comment: CXF look up the jetty engine by port, you may consider to setup the engine by using different bus.